# negative margin-top in combination with floats doesn't work as expected (only in Firefox)

Tags: html, css, margin

I want try to create this screen, but text fields on the right side are shifted above.

[image: Mockup]

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/KjakS/1/) and here is my code:

*HTML:*

```
<div class="TileMenu">
    <div class="TileRow">
        <div class="LeftTile">
            <div class="TileImage">
                <img src="http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/krudolph/stuff/stackoverflow.png" title="Castle" alt="Castle" />
            </div>
            <div class="TileText">
                <p>Text1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="RightTile">
            <div class="TileImage">
                <img src="http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/krudolph/stuff/stackoverflow.png" title="House" alt="House" />
            </div>
            <div class="TileText">
                <p>Text 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TileRow">
        <div class="LeftTile">
            <div class="TileImage">
                <img src="http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/krudolph/stuff/stackoverflow.png" title="Satellite" alt="Satellite" />
            </div>
            <div class="TileText">
                <p>Text 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="RightTile">
            <div class="TileImage">
                <img src="http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/krudolph/stuff/stackoverflow.png" title="Palace" alt="Palace" />
            </div>
            <div class="TileText">
                <p>Text 4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.TileRow{
    padding: 5px 0px;
    clear: both;
}

.LeftTile{
    width: 49.7%;
    float: left;
    /*height: 340px;
    overflow: hidden;*/
}

.LeftTile img{
    width: 100%;
}

.RightTile{
    width: 49.7%;
    float: right;
    /*height: 340px;
    overflow: hidden;*/
}

.RightTile img{
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
}

.TileImage{
    width: 49.7%;
}

.TileText{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -80px;
    max-width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #57abe9;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: table;
}

.TileText p{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

Before I tried to use `top:-80px;` but than I got a big white space between each row (because of the text field). So now I'm using `margin-top: -80px;` but this seems only to work in Firefox.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see what the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried to view the example with IE9, Chrome, Opera, Safari? Text2 and Text4 are shifted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about position: absolute?

http://jsfiddle.net/KjakS/8/

Comment: +1 - this is a perfect example of when to use `position: absolute`. Although you should move your code example into your answer.

Comment: I tried to use `position:absolute` before (on `TileImage` and on `TileText`). But than my layout got destroyed and I didn't used `top`. You instead used `position: relative` on `RigthTile` and on `LeftTile` in combination with `position: absolute` on `TileText` and `top`. Perhaps you would like to explain the solution in more detail to me?

Comment: `position: absolute` is placed relatively within the nearest positioned box. So to keep it relative to its immediate parent you must give the parent element a position other than `static` (default). We give it `position: relative` in this instance so it is kept in the flow of the document. I would also use `bottom` rather than `top`, since you are positioning closer to the bottom of the box.

Comment: After you add position:relative to the container, inner element with position:absolute will refer to that container instead of whole document.

Comment: Also, if you used `position: absolute` on both elements (`TileImage` and `TileText`) then that would not have worked either as that would take them both out of the flow of the document and the parent box would have no height. So you would only position the `TileText` absolutely as you would want `TileImage` to dictate the height.

Answer (score 1):

What if you remove the `float:right` on the image in the RightTile class? To something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/KjakS/7/

`.RightTile img{
    width: 100%;
}`